# htaccess rewrite non html request

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've migrate a dynamic .asp site to static site by using sitesucker osx app...
everything works done if you access directly!

old url:

```
http://www.mysite.com/content.asp?L=1&IdMen=158‎
```

new url:

```
http://www.mysite.com/content.asp-L=1&IdMen=158‎.html
```

i get page not found from my old referral inbound links (google, yahoo etc...)

i would like, by using .htaccess, redirect all links that not contains ".html" to permanent redirect too html page...

i've tried this but not work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [R=301,L]
```

many thanks
Frankie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per examples if you want to modify query string then you need this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !\.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule !\.html$ %{REQUEST_URI}-%{QUERY_STRING}.html? [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: With this rule: `/content.asp?L=1&IdMen=158‎` becomes `/content.asp?L=1&IdMen=158‎.html` is that how you wanted right?

Comment: almost works... the redirect point to: 
`http://www.mysite.com/content.asp?L=1&IdMen=158‎?.html`
and none to:
`http://www.mysite.com/content.asp?L=1&IdMen=158‎.html`

i need to redirect without **?** before .html

Comment: yes is what i want...
but on my web server become `/content.asp?L=1&IdMen=158‎.?html`

Comment: Ok make sure **this is your first rule**. I have tested it again and `/content.asp?L=1&IdMen=158‎` is redirected to `/content.asp?L=1&IdMen=158‎.html`. Also make sure to test in a new browser. I will be offline for couple of hours then check back.

Comment: the redirect works (i try with new browser)...
but unfortunately i get this message: 
Not Found

`The requested URL /content.asp was not found on this server.`

thats is correct, because [content.asp] there isn't but [content.asp?L=1&IdMen=158‎.html] exist

I'm confused

Comment: What happens if you directly open this URL in your browser `/content.asp?L=1&IdMen=158‎.html` ?

Comment: Ok rule is working fine on my web server. If you post your latest .htaccess in your question I can check what is wrong.

Comment: does not work! 
I am very sorry but I was wrong to write the static link ... 
the static link that works is: 
`content.asp-L=1&IdMen=158.html`
then I would need to rewrite the url with - and not with?

Comment: But that is different URL scheme from your question above, isn't it?

Comment: i've check updated code and this is the result: `content.asp-L=1&IdMen=158.html-.html-.html-.html-.html-.html-.html-.html-.html-.html-.html-.html-.html-.html-.html-.html-.html-.html-.html-.html-.html-.html`

Comment: You didn't copy/paste right. See updated code. There is `?` at the end of `.html?` in target URI.

Comment: ok thats work perfectly... the little issue is that rewrite all extension (ex. gif|css|jpg etc...)